# Entity Framework: Apply operations between time intervals optimization

Tags: c#, time, entity-framework-core, intervals

**Problem definition:**
I have a database table with millions of entries.This table is defined with the following columns: Date,Value and NumberOfEvents. I need to get the data between several time intervals, and apply a function (Sum, Average, Max, Min) on all the returned records for each interval.

**Current Solution:**

```
   List<SingleSeries> series = new List<SingleSeries>();
            //Iterate intervals
            for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                }
                if (i + 1 < intervals.Count())
                {
                    //Get database entries between interval
                    var validKpis = kpis.Where(x => x.Date >= intervals.ElementAt(i) && x.Date < intervals.ElementAt(i + 1));
                    //Apply calc operation (SUM; AVG; MAX;MIN)
                    var result= CalcOperations.Calculate(calcOperation, validKpis);
                    //Add result to results array
                    series.Add(new SingleSeries()
                    {
                        Value = result,
                        Name = DateOperations.ConvertToMilliseconds(intervals.ElementAt(i + 1)).ToString()
                    });
                };
            }
            return series;
```

**Current Problem:**
Currently this function does N Queries to database where N=intervals.Count()/2. I would like it to do just **one database trip** but i cant figure out how to use the interval array to aggregate the values **for each interval** and apply the calc operation **on it**.
Sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up a single query which will fetch the results for *all intervals* and then cycle through the intervals to split that result set into those for each specific interval.

Its a little more code, but much more efficient use of database requests.

Here's a rough snippet demonstrating the above - note that I havent tested this - its just to give you a concrete idea of how to go about doing this with a single query.

```
        List<SingleSeries> series = new List<SingleSeries>();
        var kpiQuery = kpis;

        //Iterate intervals and build a single query to retrieve all of them
        for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < intervals.Count())
            {
                // add each target interval sequentially - without running the query yet
                kpiQuery = kpiQuery.Where(x => x.Date >= intervals.ElementAt(i) && x.Date < intervals.ElementAt(i + 1));
            }
        }

        var validKpis = kpiQuery.ToList(); // now get all database results in a single transaction

        //Iterate the intervals again, this time to split the combined results that are now in memory
        for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < intervals.Count())
            {
                //select only the results applicable to the current interval
                var kpisInThisInterval = validKpis.Where(x =>
                    x.Date >= intervals.ElementAt(i) && x.Date < intervals.ElementAt(i + 1));

                //Apply calc operation (SUM; AVG; MAX;MIN)
                var result = CalcOperations.Calculate(calcOperation, kpisInThisInterval);
                //Add result to results array
                series.Add(new SingleSeries()
                {
                    Value = result,
                    Name = DateOperations.ConvertToMilliseconds(intervals.ElementAt(i + 1)).ToString()
                });
            }
        }

        return series;
```

Comment: There is a problem with this line: var validKpis = kpiQuery.ToList(); This will bring millions of records in memory... not a good solution for me but a good solution for small datasets

Comment: @Ricky it will only retrieve the records that match your intervals. The first for loop builds a query which fetchs those records in a single transaction. Records that *dont match any interval* will not be returned.

Comment: Yes that is true. But the total amount of records in memory would still be thousands if not millions.

Comment: @Ricky - then why, in your question, did you say: *"I would like it to do just one query"* ?

Comment: Sorry I meant one database trip

Comment: @Ricky that is effectively the same thing. Whatever way you do it, to run your calculation you need to have the records in memory - your choice to to pull them in a single operation (or db trip, if you want to call it that) which will mean all records are loaded simultaneosly, meaning your memory usage could be high - or in multiple requests which controls your memory usage but means you have many db ops. The choice is yours - but from what you're saying I dont think you have given this enough thought. Perhaps you should look into whether you can do this in a stored procedure.